# Why this code do not work in second time click button

Tags: delphi

I write this code for button click event . the first time I click the button every thing work correctly but when click for the second time on button it raise an error. whats the problem?

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  B : Boolean;
begin
  DM.tblTemp.DisableControls;
  B:= DM.tblTemp.Locate('FoodName', DM.tblAsli.FieldByName('FoodName').AsString,[]) ;
  if  B then
  begin
    DM.tblTemp.Edit;
    DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('Number').AsInteger:=  DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('Number').AsInteger + 1;
    DM.tblTemp.Post;
  end
  else
  begin
    DM.tblTemp.insert;
    DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('FoodName').AsString := DM.tblAsli.FieldByName('FoodName').AsString;
    DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('UnitPrice').AsInteger := DM.tblAsli.FieldByName('FoodPrice').AsInteger;
    DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('Number').AsInteger := 1;
    DM.tblTemp.Post;
  end;
  TotalPrice:= TotalPrice + DM.tblTemp.FieldByName('TotalPrice').AsInteger;
  DM.tblTemp.EnableControls;
end;
```

the Error is

> Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed
> since it was last read

DM is data madual
tmbTbl is ADOTable

Comment: Although most people probably can guess it, you really should state the type of `tblTemp` (and `DM`). One shouldn't need to guess the types in a Q. Also, you should include the error message and the line number of the line that raises the exception.

Comment: Well, you stilll didn't say on which line the exception occurs, so -1 for that.  If, as I suspect it's on the .Post line, this usually means that it is the ADO layer which can't find which row to update and that's usually solved by adding a primary key to the table.

Comment: @KenWhite:  Not sure about the dupe - I can't reproduce the error using either the Sql Server OLE DB provider or the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 one.  Still, if the OP doesn't provide the requisite details ...

Comment: @MartynA: The dupe mentions a change necessary in the connection string. Unless the poster can provide more details that show the other one is not a dupe, it looks like one to me. If the poster edits the question to provide sufficient details to make the dupe incorrect, the question can be reopened.

Comment: @MartynA thaks alot. the problem sloved by adding primary key to table

Comment: @KenWhite:  In view of the OP's latest comment about adding a pk, I've voted to re-open the q.

Comment: @MartynA: Works for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is a pity you haven't said which DBMS you are using (e.g. Sql Server or MS Access,
nor told us a full list of the table's column types and indexes, if any.

The most likely answer to your q is that the variable B is set to False the first time
because the call to tblTemp.Locate fails to locate the Food name in question, so the Insert branch executes and the food's data is
added to the table but the second time the Edit branch executes  and the error occurs,
though you have not said where, exactly.  My guess would be on the call to .Post, because
the error message is one the ADO layer, which sits between the DBMS provider and your app,
emits when it attempts to post a change to the table but cannot identify which table row to update.
As I mentioned in a comment, the fix to this is usually at add a primary key index to the table, and I gather from your latest comment that this has succeeded for you.  For the record and benefit of future readers it would be helpful if you could confirm which DBMS you are using and which Ole Driver you are using in your connection string.

Fwiw, I've tested your code using a table on MS Sql Server and MS Access and do not get the
error with either database.

Btw there is an obvious q, "How is it that tblTemp.Locate succeeds, but ADO is unable to
identify the correct record to post the update?"  The answer is that tblTemp.Locate works in
a different way than identifying the relevant row to post the update.

Comment: As I said, it would be good if you could be kind enough to accept this answer (by clicking the 'tick' icon on its left).